# Delete confirmation when deleting from floating menu in a page editor in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, page-editor

I am very new sitecore, working with sitecore 7.
The question is when I am in a page editor, when I delete an item using the floating menu 'delete' function, It just deletes the item.

Customer requirement is to add a confirmation box here. Something like 'are you sure to delete'. and two typical buttons(yes/cancel).

is that even possible? any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
In the picture below, The red cross, is a delete/remove button. If I click it just deletes. I want to show confirmation upon clicking the button.

[image]

EDIT 2:

Ok, I am writing a custom command.
I have added a new button. The target is this new button will ask if the user wants to remove the component or not. And if user says 'yes' it will do the same as the default built in remove button does.

[image]

Code:

```cs
public class RemoveWithNoti:Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.WebEditCommand
    {
        public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
        {

            Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "Run", context.Parameters);
        }

    protected static void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (args.HasResult)
            {
                //Here I need to call "chrome:rendering:delete" this . I just dont know how to!!

            }
        }
        else
        {
            SheerResponse.Confirm("Are you certain that you want to remove this component");
            args.WaitForPostBack();
        }
    }
    }
```

How do I call chrome:rendering:delete from code??

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about the page editor and not the content editor? If it's really the page editor, what exactly are you trying to delete? Please clarify, maybe even provide a screenshot.

Comment: yes page editor it is. I am trying to delete some component.

Comment: Did you try to ask Sitecore Support?

Comment: No. Will they help? I mean I don't know if they help with programming stuff !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "chrome:rendering:delete" event is handled on the client side by javascript. Here is the exact places:
/sitecore/shell/Applications/Page Modes/ChromeTypes/RenderingChromeType.js file:

```js
handleMessage: function(message, params, sender) {
    switch (message) {
...
      case "chrome:rendering:delete": 
        this.deleteControl();
        break;
...
},
```

You can do something like this in the same file:

```js
deleteControl: function() {
    if(confirm('Are you sure to remove this component?')){
        var placeholder = this.getPlaceholder();

        if (placeholder) {     
          placeholder.type.deleteControl(this.chrome);      
        }
    }
}
```